# Looking for a Trio based Fantasy series for Children

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a Trio based Fantasy Series for Children, please help.

It is based on Harry Potter like theme, not very old – released after Harry Potter. It's a fantasy series, featuring three orphan kids.

Comment: With this little information, the answer could be almost anything. Can you remember any character names, events, location, setting, whether they had weapons or use of magic, who were the antagonists, when you read it, what format was it in, how many books in the series, any notable phrases used?

Comment: His Dark Materials, Narnia series, Eragon?

Comment: Sorry Richard, I don't have much information. The book released after Harry Potter. And has a Trio, I couldn't google it.

Comment: It is based on 3 orphan kids.

Comment: It is a Fantasy series :-)

Comment: A Series of Unfortunate Events *is* a fantasy series. Do you mean **"sword & sorcery"**?

Comment: By "trio", you mean a group of three main protagonists? Do you remember if they were children, youths or adults? Girls or boys? By "not very old", how old do you think? When did you see it? Do you remember what the cover looked like, a phrase or word from it, or anything more specific?

Comment: @Richard Please use comments to improve the question, and reserve possible answers for answer posts.

Answer (score 5):

[image: The Emerald Atlas by John Stephens - Book Cover] [image]

Not very old, huh? How about the (pretty recent) **[The Books of Beginning](http://www.randomhouse.com/kids/emeraldatlas/)** series by [John Stephens](http://www.randomhouse.com/kids/emeraldatlas/author.php), first published in 2011. It begins with [**The Emerald Atlas**](http://www.kidsreads.com/reviews/the-emerald-atlas), followed by [**The Fire Chronicle**](http://www.kidsreads.com/reviews/the-fire-chronicle-books-of-beginning). The third installment, [**The Black Reckoning**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375868720), is slated for 2015.

Here's a synopsis for the first book:

> The Emerald Atlas follows orphan siblings Kate, Michael, and Emma who,
>   following a succession of unsuccessful orphanage dwellings, are
>   transferred to the mansion of Dr. Pym, where they find a magical book
>   that grants the power of moving through time. Upon traveling to the
>   past, they happen across a witch who has enslaved the nearby town in
>   an attempt to find the book, known as the Atlas, that the children
>   possess. As the siblings encounter various magical races in an effort
>   to dispel the witch, Kate discovers that she is intrinsically bound to
>   the Atlas, and that the three children are subject to an ancient
>   prophecy. ~ *Edited from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emerald_Atlas)*

Comment: @reemuskumar No problem, glad to help! Don't forget to mark this one as 'answered' :-)